# On solving $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}}}=\sqrt[3]{6+\sqrt[3]{6+\sqrt[3]{6+\sqrt[3]{6+x}}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

How do we show that there is only one solution to,$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}}}=\sqrt[3]{6+\sqrt[3]{6+\sqrt[3]{6+\sqrt[3]{6+x}}}}$$

I guess it is only $x=2$.
Please help.

Comment: So no one else has to type it in: [W|A only finds $x=2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282+%2B+sqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2Bx%29%29%29%29+%3D+cubert%286%2Bcubert%286%2Bcubert%286%2Bcubert%286%2Bx%29%29%29%29&a=*FunClash.cubert-_*Cbrt-)

Comment: The four who voted to close chose the option: "_This question does not appear to be about math within the scope defined in the help center._"  Really?!

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: Thanks for edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $\;f(x) = \sqrt{2+x}\;$ and $\;g(x) = \sqrt[3]{6+x}$, they are strictly increasing function in $x$ when $x \ge -2$.
Since $(x+2)^3 - (x+6)^2 = (x-2)(x^2 + 7x + 14)$ and $x^2 + 7x + 14 > 0$ for all $x$,
we have
$$\begin{cases} f(x) > g(x) > 2,& x > 2\\f(x) = g(x) = 2,& x = 2\\f(x) < g(x) < 2, & x <2\end{cases}$$
So for any $x > 2$, we have
$$\begin{align}
& f(x) > g(x) > 2\\
\implies & f(f(x)) > f(g(x)) > g(g(x)) > 2\\
\implies & f(f(f(x))) > f(g(g(x)) > g(g(g(x)) > 2\\
\implies & f(f(f(f(x))) > f(g(g(g(x))) > g(g(g(g(x)))) > 2\\
\implies & f(f(f(f(x))) \ne g(g(g(g(x))))
\end{align}$$
Please note that in above deductions, we are using following reasoning repeatedly.
$$\underbrace{g\circ\cdots\circ g(x)}_{k \text{ terms}} > 2 
\implies 
f(\underbrace{g\circ\cdots\circ g(x)}_{k \text{ terms}}) >
\underbrace{g\circ\cdots\circ g(x)}_{k+1 \text{ terms}} > 2.$$

Similar logic shows that $f(f(f(f(x)))) \ne g(g(g(g(x))))$ for $x < 2$. As a result,
$x = 2$ is the only solution for the equation $f(f(f(f(x)))) = g(g(g(g(x))))$.

Comment: Should we vote to have this re-opened?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII sure, why not. the question itself is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

A proof by induction.
Let:
$$f_n(x) =  \sqrt[3]{6+\sqrt[3]{6+\ldots+\sqrt[3]{6+x}}},\ g_n(x) = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots+\sqrt{2+x}}}$$
With $n$ terms. Then for $n=1$ you can easily solve the cubic equation to show that $f_1=g_1 $ only at $x=2$ (over the reals).

Now assume our claim is true for $n$, i.e. that $f_n(x)=g_n(x)$  iff for $x=2$. Then for $n+1$, raise to the sixth power to get that:
$$(6+f_n(x))^2=(2+g_n(x))^3$$
Clearly, this equality is true for $x=2$ since $f_n(2)=g_n(2)$. Now, if our claim is false and this equality holds for some $x_0\neq 2$, then:
$$g_n(x_0) = (6+f_n(x_0))^{2/3}-2$$
But since $dg_n/df_n < 1$ for all $x>0$, by the mean value theorem we have a contradiction.
$$$$
**Thus we have proven that for any number of $n$ the only (real) solution of $f_n(x)=g_n(x)$ is $x=2$.**

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure how you are using the MVT here.

Comment: @Braindead - just to prove that if $g(x)=h(x)$ at some point, and the derivative of one is is always greater then the other, they will never coincide.

Comment: Okay, so you assume that $f_{n+1}(x_0) = g_{n+1}(x_0)$ for some $x_0 \ne2$. Then you get that equation. But how / where do you get $g'_n < f'_n$ for all $x>0$?

Comment: @Braindead  - do the math :) take the derivative $dg/df$ and show it is smaller than one.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII - sure, it's a nice question :)

Comment: @nbubis - I don't understand what you are taking the derivative of, or why this derivative even makes any sense. $x_0$ is a fixed number. $f_n$ and $g_n$ are fixed functions.

Comment: nbubis: I already did. Your turn.  :)

Comment: @Braindead - look at $g$ as a function of $f$, and compare to $f$. It's like showing that $g(y)>y$ if $g(y_0)=y_0$ and $g'(y) < 1$ for all $y\neq y_0$.

Comment: @nbubis - In your proof, you assume that the equality $g_n(x_0) = (6+f_n(x_0))^{2/3} -2$ holds at some fixed point $x_0 \ne 2$. How do you go from that statement to $g_n(x) = (6+f_n(x))^{2/3} -2$ for $x>0$?

Comment: @Braindead - you are correct - it should be for $x>-2$$ which is the domain.

Comment: @nbubis - No no, that's not what I was referring to. I simply don't follow the logic of your proof: how do you obtain the equality $g_n(x)=(6+f_n(x))^{2/3} -2$ away from the fixed point $x_0$?

Comment: @Braindead - there is no equality - I'm assumng there is just to get a contradiction.i

Comment: @nbubis Sorry. I had meant to say I don't see how you are using your induction hypothesis to arrive at a contradiction from assuming $f_{n+1}(x_0) = g_{n+1}(x_0)$ at a number other than 2. I feel like you are telling me to take the derivative of the expression $g_n(x_0) = (6+f_n(x_0))^{2/3} -2$, but that makes no sense to me as you are assuming that the equality holds at some given point $x_0$. If you could expand your proof in your answer, I would greatly appreciate it, because I simply do not follow your logic.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid solution. Maybe someone can explain it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: raise both sides to the sixth power.

Comment: Doesn't that make things worse?

Comment: Oh, ok. But there really should be a policy that if more than one person has already given a substantial answer, then that question should not be closed.

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way. I would just let x equal to a number that's 2, less than 2, and greater than 2. Through trial and error, you can see that x = 2 is the only acceptable answer for this problem. If the question requires a proof, you could do it by induction. I'm just starting out, so I can't really do it yet...only through what I could see at the moment.